# Error installing Visual Studio 2015 on my Windows 10 system

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, team-explorer

Your help will be appreciated...

When i try to install Visual Studio 2015 it throws an error while installing Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

I tried installing from ISO, even extracted the content of it and tried to install from it too... but in vein.

**Here is the screenshot of the error**

[image: ![Visual Studio Error]]


**LOG file is attached too**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/npnp5r44z3azj8t/dd_vs_enterprise_20160301132449.log?dl=0

Comment: I am unable to view your log file. I clicked on it, but I don't see any log file. Try putting this information into your question. At least the relevant portions.

Comment: Could it be that your iso is corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

I finally reinstalled my Windows 10 and same ISO worked